# multiple root users in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I have just reset my root password after a long struggle. I see there are three root users in phpmyadmin. Should I delete two roots and keep only one or I need all the three?

(I am afraid of keeping three roots and changing the root password, may not allow me to enter phpmyadmin again due to multiple root ambiguity. I just wonder how three root users have been created. isn't that localhost and the local IP 127.0.0.1 refer to same local server/system? )

Thanks in Advance for any help,

Answer (score 4):

First of all, there is no such thing as phpmyadmin users. These users are defined in mysql. Phpmyadmin only manages mysql databases.

As @urfusion has pointed out, in mysql a user is made up of an username and a host name part in form of `'user_name'@'host_name'`. Host name refers to the computer from which the connection is made. If 2 user accounts have the same username, but different host names, then those are not the same users, even though their access rights might be the same.

The complication in mysql is that a computer may be identified through its name (e.g. mycomputer) or its IP address (e.g. 1.1.1.1), depending on whether mysql is able to resolve the IP address of the host or not. This is why mysql comes with a `'root'%'localhost'` and a `'root'%'127.0.0.1'`, just to make sure that you can connect initially regardless if IP address resolution works or not.

If the host name is left blank or contains `'%'`, it means that with that user id you can connect from any machine. This is the 3rd default root user in mysql.

If you do not want to connect to your mysql database from a different computer as root, then you can remove the `'root'%'%'` account. This depends on your operational environment. If php (webserver) runs on the same computer where mysql is, then phpmyadmin requires a user account with localhost or 127.0.0.1 hostname only.

However, I would leave the `'root'%'localhost'` and a `'root'%'127.0.0.1'` intact just in case IP address resolution does not work. I would also make sure that their access rights are exactly the same (by default they are).

Comment: That's so informative. cleared the fundamental concepts. Thank you. When I change root password it changes password of root%localhost. for the other two root accounts it shows no password in the users list. Arn't they vulnerable to security risks? in phpmyadmin i think the password is given only when we create a user. so to change root%IP or root%1 i will have to use command prompt or sql query? Also while accessing through phpmyadmin can I give root@localhost or root@127.0.0.1 in username to access the particular user session?

Comment: You can change a user's password using alter user or set password sql commands. Phpmyadmin also offers this feature in its GUI, without typing the sql commands. Yes, user accounts without password are a security risk. If they can only be used from the localhost mitigates the risk somewhat, but does not eliminate it. I do not understand your last question.

Comment: Actually when i am changing password through xampp/security page, it is not allowing me to login in phpmyadmin with this password. I am able to access the phpmyadmin only after inserting skip_grant_tables below [sqld] in mysql/bin/my.ini. After loging in this way any sql command including 'set password' shows error that query can not be executed due to server running in skip-grant-tables mode. Is there any way i can make all roots secure and operable? In attempt to resolve this i wanted to try login in phpmyadmin specifying the host name also, specifying not only 'root' but also  the host too.

Comment: This is server administration and not sw development question. Remove the changed passwords for the root users, login with blank password to mysql via phpmyadmin and change the password there. If you have further questions on this topic, then I suggest to raise the question on serverfault, rather the SO.

Comment: ok. thank you so much for your replies. ( Phpmyadmin is not allowing me to do anything, its giving error message that server is running on skip-grant-tables mode)

Comment: Find the password field in mysql.user table and make it blank for your user. Then restart mysql service. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant-table-structure.html

Comment: yes it worked. thanks you so much. I am writing all steps here, may help some one with same problem..

Comment: 1) Entering into phpmyadmin by inserting a line skip_grant_tables below the line [sqld] in xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini. 2) select user table in mysql database in left panel. 3) on right panel choose edit for the desired root user. 4) make the field password field blank deleting all characters of long string. click on go ....

Comment: 5) delete the skip_grant_tables line from my.ini, save the file and restart mysql 6)enter phpmyadmin without password for username root 7) change the root password clicking on users tab in right panel 8) system will show a popup window about password change successfully. 9) refresh the browser. .....you may like to change all root users with same password.

Answer (score 0):

Phpmyadmin(actually MySql) users are identified by a pair of username and `hostname`. `127.0.0.1`, `::1`, and `localhost` all allow you access from your local machine. Without them, you would not be able to connect.

So I didn't recommend you to delete other users

please check [users](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_usage) for more information.

[delete root user](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/deleted-root-user-from-phpmyadmin-mamp/97974)

Comment: There is no such thing as phpmyadmin users. These are users defined in mysql.

Comment: Yes you are right. I wrote that for understanding for user